# How to check whether names in a column are only what's in the defined array using Python

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

I am in the process of predicting FIFA 2022 winning team. I defined an array including the teams assumed to be in the final 32 teams in the game and now I want to check whether the home_team column and away_team column includes only those teams. I want to create a new variable that would say Yes/No. But, I am finding it hard to proceed with the code I have built.
I am in need of help.

```
def checkIfValuesExists1(df_teams, worldcup_teams):
  resultdic={}
  for elem in worldcup_teams:
    if elem in df_teams.values:
      resultdic[elemen]=True
    else:
      resultDic[elem]=False
  return resultDict
```

[The array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkydh.png)
[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY5Ny.png)

Comment: Please post the code you posted in the image as plain text, not as an image.  Also, looking at that code, I'm not really sure what is wrong with what you already had using the `isin()` method?

Comment: Where is elemen defined?